# Hillshade input field for z factor keeps rounding value in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hillshade

In QGIS 3.8.0, the Hillshade tool
when I try to input the value for the z-factor which for my case should be
0.00000956 exactly, after you remove focus of the input field QGIS rounds that number to 0.00001

This goes for other tools as well not just Hillshade and it was working just fine as expected before, so I guess this some kind of a configuration issue maybe ? I uninstalled and reinstalled but it is still there.

[image]

Comment: it's probably a UI formatting issue - use the command line tool for complete control. But isn't that a very small number to use for Z-factor, I usually use 5-7.

Comment: yup the command line works, i copy from the end of the tool there but just tedious i don't know what's wrong with the program !
as for the z-factor, no the number should be between 0-1 and this depends on the latitude of your data reference is here
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/imagery/setting-the-z-factor-parameter-correctly/

Comment: I think that in [GDAL terms](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html) what ESRI call Z-factor is the scale factor (well 1 over the scale factor), while Z-factor is the vertical exaggeration which allows for the fact that hills are very small compared to the horizontal distance.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330482/what-should-i-set-vertical-exaggeration-to-in-gdaldem for further thoughts