# What should I set vertical exaggeration to in gdaldem?

Tags: qgis, gdal, hillshade

In the comments to [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330470/qgis-hillshade-input-field-for-z-factor-keeps-rounding-value) I suggested that I would use a value of between 5 and 7 for the vertical exaggeration in [`gdaldem`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html). The questioner pointed to the [ESRI docs](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/imagery/setting-the-z-factor-parameter-correctly/) where they suggest a value related the pixel size of your data (and recommend a value of 0.00000956 if your data is geographic and the heights are in metres).

I had always assumed that value went into the `scale` parameter and that vertical exaggeration was used to overcome the fact that even the Himalayas are "small" in height when compared to the extent of the map and have traditionally used a value of 7 (or so) when creating hill shades.

So who is right?

Comment: Vertical exaggeration selection  is very subjective and data-dependent. I've used values from 5 to 25 with various projects. I doubt there is a "should" value which could be recommended.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, style, scale etc, tweak it til you like the result. It's art, not something analytical.

Comment: If the both the data and height are in meter (like working with projected data), changing the Z value to a higher one will be just a matter of vertical exaggeration preference. But dealing with data in geographic and heights in meter, choosing a proper value such as the one mentioned in your question is to handle the difference in units. In this case it is not meant for vertical exaggeration but to get a correct meaningful height.

Comment: Even if the goal is to get *unexaggerated* values, you run into complications with decimal degrees units due to the pixels being spheroidal trapezoids. The variability across the study area and differences between study areas changes what "looks right" there as well.